# Web Service c# WebMethod return type

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, asmx

I am currently learning Web Services and I am wondering what return type I should use in my Web Methods.

I am trying to do an exercise (in c#) on web services that implies simulating a library. In my client, I am supposed to use the web service without having access to the classes. At least, that's what I think.

For exemple, I am supposed to receive the information about a book (title, isbn, etc...) without having access to the class that describes books.

When a web method returns a book, I understand that the book is serialized and sent to the client who is requesting it. In my c# client, I'm guessing that if I receive a Book, it means I have access to the class that describes a Book.

I think I am supposed to use a string to communicate with my client, since the client does not have access to the classes. (like this web service : http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL which returns a string that contains XML, and then the client can use XMLDocument to parse XML and do whatever he wants with the data he received)

I have 2 questions: Is this solution the best way to use web services? (using a string containing XML to communicate with clients which don't have access to the classes).
If so, do I need to convert manually the object into an XMLDocument and then convert the xml to a string and then send this string, or... am I wrong and there is a better way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I understand but in my school, I have to use it in order to understand how it works, even if I should use other technologies for new development. I learnt WCF too but I am not supposed to use it in this exercise.

Comment: Please tell your instructor that I think he's <s>an idiot</s> not very bright for teaching "old tricks to new dogs".

Comment: Sadly it doesn't solve my problem. I see your point but that is not helping me at all.

Comment: No, the best way to use web services is just "Add Service Reference", or, since your instructor is backwards, "Add Web Reference".

Comment: Thing is, even if you add a web reference, the VS will generate classes for you from WSDL. Which will be roughly equal to the server ones. But, this is intended behavior. So it'd be nice to clarify: 1) what should you have access to and what not; 2) in case no auto-generated classes should be in place - is it really about asmx web service?